# How can get Items in HTML code with VBA for automation

Tags: html, excel, vba

I use excel VBA to automation, but I have problems. I have html code like this:

```
<li class="rtLI">

    <div class="rtMid">
        <span class="rtSp"></span>
        <span class="rtPlus"></span>
        <img class="rtImg" alt=": 7036" src="https://sbpms.google.com/Images/folder.png"></img>
        <span id="7036" class="rtIn" style="color:#0033FF;" type="INXCategory" title=": 7036"></span>
        ::after
    </div>
    ::after

</li>
<li class="rtLI">

    <div class="rtMid">
        <span class="rtSp"></span>
        <span class="rtPlus"></span>
        <img class="rtImg" alt=": 7013" src="https://sbpms.google.com/Images/folder.png"></img>
        <span id="7013" class="rtIn" style="color:#0033FF;" type="INXCategory" title=": 7013"></span>
        ::after
    </div>
    <ul class="rtUL" style="height: auto; overflow: visible; display: none;"></ul>
    ::after

</li>
<li class="rtLI">

    <div class="rtMid">
        <span class="rtSp"></span>
        **<span class="rtPlus"></span>
        <img class="rtImg" alt=": 7027" src="https://sbpms.google.com/Images/folder.png"></img>
        *<span id="7027" class="rtIn" style="color:#0033FF;" type="INXCategory" title=": 7027"></span>
        ::after
    </div>
    ::after

</li>
```

VBA code I use is this:

```
    set rtLIelements = doceument.getElementsByClassName("rtLI")
For each ele in rtLIelements
    set el = ele.document.getelementByID("7027")
    if not (el is nothing) then
        set plusItem = ele.document.getElementsByClassName("rtPlus")
        exit for
    endif
Next
plusItem(0).Click
```

I want to find element **< span class="rtPlus" >< /span >** (signed with **) belongs to "li" item, that has a span with ID=7027.
ID=7027 belongs to rtLIelements(3) (signed with *)but at first iteration find pluseItem and exit but pluseItem is nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No document should be after ele
And please show us how you define the variable

It would be better for you to search online video to study how to **scrape** data from website

Comment: rtLIelements should be defined as ihtmlelementcollection